# Hive Regex is acting greedy

Tags: java, sql, regex, hive, rlike

I want to match only `911` or `1911` from a string with any number of preceding or ending `*` or `#`.

My Regex:

```
[^0-9]\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]*
```

Test code below returns true when i was expecting it to be false:

```sql
select Digits
from (select '*11911#' as Digits) A
where Digits rlike '[^0-9]\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]*'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how your regex corresponds to your requirements. It doesn't even have a `#`.

Comment: I recommend reading up on regex syntax and using a tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HYSFVB/1) to explain the current regex and possibly create a correct one for the given use case.

Comment: If I'm reading the requirement right, the regex would look something like `[*#]*1?911[*#]*`.

Comment: A little [test case on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UfTFLd/1) to @shmosel's proposed solution (I took the liberty to include start-of-string and end-of-string validation).

Comment: can you not do `INSTR (col, '911')` ? Do you have to use regex? your requirement looks simple.

Comment: Answered: it was two problems: incorrectly escaped * and extra * at the end

Answer (score 0):

BTW when escaping in Hive, you should use double-backslash: `\\*` or use `[*]`, to avoid unpredicted behavior (sometimes single backslash works as escaping, sometimes not, double backslash always works as escape in Hive).

This `'[^0-9]\\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]*'` - does not match, * correctly escaped and you have nothing before * in the string.

Let's remove [^0-9] before `\\*` and check again:

This returns no rows:

```
select Digits
from (select '*11911#' as Digits) A
where Digits rlike '\\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]'
```

Also this `'\\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]+'` does not match

And this matches:

```
'\\*[1-9]{3,4}[^0-9]*'
```

Because `*` at the end means 0 or more times, it matches perfectly: there are 4 [1-9] and zero non digits in a row.

On regex101 it works the same: last * makes it matching